# Link to download java 1.6.0_26 version for windows 64 bit machine

Tags: windows, 64-bit, java, download

I want to download java version 1.6.0_26 for my windows 64 bit machine.Can somebody provide link for it ?

Comment: Instead of asking for an old version of Java, describe what you are trying to achieve and why another version doesn't work. The question as it stands now is of little use to anyone but yourself.

Comment: The installation of Java 6 Update 26 is a huge security risk.  There have been dozens of **major** security updates to Java.  Be a good internet neighbor and keep your system updated.

Comment: @nitro2k01 - my entire team is working on this version of java so i have to install this version :)

Comment: Have you tried asking them if it the installation files exists somewhere on the network? If that version is the standard in your company, I'm sure they have the installation file lying around somehwere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your link!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u26-oth-JPR

Just do a search for 'jre-6u26-windows-x64.exe' and you'll find it there.